# JQuery toggle and remove css classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following CSS:

```
.red {background-color: #CC0000;}
.green {background-color: #009900;}
```

and my HTML is:

```
div class="red" id="ch1">Content</div>
<div class="red" id="ch2">Content</div>
<div class="red" id="ch3">Content</div>
...
<div class="green" id="ch..">Content</div>
<div class="red" id="ch..">Content</div>
```

and I am using the following script to change class on divs:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
$(".red , .green").click(function(){
    $(".green").removeClass("green").addClass("red");
     $(this).toggleClass('red green');
});   
});
```

Works fine to change div class onclick from .red to .green but when I click on the "green" the div doesn't becomes "red". I other words I would like to have or all "red" or just ONE "green" div
ALSO nothing is working if I change the sequence of .red - .green in my CSS

Any thoughts? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not include the element that is clicked...

```
$(".green").not(this).removeClass("green").addClass("red");
```

Answer (score 1):

Only using toggleClass() should work.
So remove following line from your code
$(".green").removeClass("green").addClass("red");

**Solution:-**

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $(".red , .green").click(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('red green');
    });   
});
```

Is this what you are expecting?
http://jsfiddle.net/k23g3ne4/

Answer (score 0):

this is working :

```
$(this).siblings('.red , .green')
  .removeClass("green")
  .addClass("red");
```